# Parse complex xml with JSoup

Tags: android, xml-parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to parse complex XML file with JSoup, hovewer when getting XML like this:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www" xmlns:y="http://" xmlns:thr="http:">
 <id>5</id>
 <title>List of friends posts</title>
 <updated>2014-01-13T18:36:06Z</updated>
 <entry>
    <text>ttt</text>
 </entry>
 <entry>
    <text>aaa</text>
 </entry>
 </feed>
```

It doesn't see "entry" subtree, just like there is none.
Code:

```
doc3 = Jsoup.parse(doc2.toString(), "", Parser.xmlParser());
Elements feed = doc3.select("feed entry");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
String xml = "<feed xmlns=\"http://www\" xmlns:y=\"http://\" xmlns:thr=\"http:\">"
    +"<id>5</id>"
    +"<title>List of friends posts</title>"
    +"<updated>2014-01-13T18:36:06Z</updated>"
    +"<entry>"
    +"   <text>ttt</text>"
    +"</entry>"
    +"<entry>"
    +"   <text>aaa</text>"
    +"</entry>"
    +"</feed>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml);
Elements feed = doc.select("feed entry");
```

Comment: Oh, really! Now I realize, that the problem was not in JSoup, but in authorization. Err..nevermind. Thanks!